# Cassandra's Metrics Monitoring native API

Tags: java, json, cassandra, dropwizard, metrics

I want to capture Dropwizard Metrics of my Cassandra cluster in my Java Program(I don't want to use JMX) and pass those values in JSON to some other server(which will use these values to generate alarms etc). I'm new in Java and would really appreciate if I can get some guidance. Are there any native Dropwizard APIs for collecting these metrics? Can you provide a sample Java code of using that API for fetching any metric for example? The reason for not using JMX is that I've read [here](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/core) that it's not recommended to try to gather metrics from production environment as JMX’s RPC API is fragile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send metrics using available plugins for Metrics library, such as graphite, or ganglia...

To do this, you need to put `.jar` file for corresponding plugin into `lib` directory of Cassandra, add corresponding configuration file for plugin, modify Cassandra's `jvm.options` file with following line:

```
-Dcassandra.metricsReporterConfigFile=<reporting-configuration>.yaml
```

and restart Cassandra to pickup the changes.

There are several blog post on configuration of Cassandra to use custom metrics plugins that could provide more details: [1](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/pluggable-metrics-reporting-in-cassandra-2-0-2), [2](https://softwaremill.com/cassandra-monitoring-part-2/).

You may also try to setup standard [Metrics Servlets](http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#reporting-via-http) to do query - it should be configured almost the same way - add library & provide configuration

Comment: As per my current knowledge, Graphite/Ganglia are graphical tools to display metrics and raise alarms and they are not what I need. I just want to fetch all the performance metrics from each of my Cassandra nodes(on demand) and convert them into JSON format. Since I'm new to Java, it's been overwhelming for me to wrap my head around so many new things. The metrics website mentions a lot of ways/tools in which the metrics can be used. I'm not even sure if all of those methods will work in Cassandra. I think it will all make sense as I understand Java more.

Comment: These are system for collection & display of metrics. You can use some other plugins (http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/third-party/) that report data. And I would recommend that you won't go to nodes for metrics, but instead push metrics from cassandra - it will be more flexible

Comment: I've updated the answer with pointer to http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/getting-started/#reporting-via-http

Comment: (metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/third-party) contains so many new names for me..I don't even know what will be useful although it seems to me there's no library which will fetch the metrics and report in json format! On the side-pane, I saw JSON support option, http://metrics.dropwizard.io/3.1.0/manual/json/, but since this does not come pre-included with cassandra, I don't know how to make it work(I'm assuming it does what I want i.e. fetch the metrics and convert them into JSON format).

Comment: At the moment, MetricsServlets and metrics-json seem to me the options that I should explore.